# ClearInterval not working (but only sometimes) for sever api call

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, setinterval

I have this function that is supposed to query the database every 4 seconds for any new content that may have been posted. I then take the return and refresh a feed with dynamic html made from whatever came back from the server. This all works great.

My problem is that as part of the html there is a options tray that they can press that will slide over part of the content and give them different options to do with that content, delete, copy, comment stuff like that. Well when they pop out the tray I want to clear the interval timer so that it does not refresh the html on in the feed (making the tray go away).

The other problem is that the user can have multiple trays open at the same time so I came up with this function to handle it all:

```
function setTimers(status)
{
    var timerGetContent = null;
    if(status == "login")
    {
        tray_count = 0;
        timerGetContent = null;
        timerGetContent = setInterval(getContent,4000);
        alert("inside login");
    }
    else if(status == "negitive")
    {
        tray_count--;
        if(tray_count == 0 && timerGetContent == null)
        {
            timerGetContent = setInterval(getRecentContent,4000);
            alert("inside negitive");
        }
    }
    else if(status == "positive")
    {
        tray_count++;
        clearInterval(timerGetContent);
        timerGetContent = null;
        alert("inside positive")
    }

}
```

So when the user presses the button to pop out the tray it calls `setTimer` and passes it positive before it does anything else, and then when they press the button to close the tray it calls `setTimer` and passes it negitive. I know the calls work and that its being passed the right parameters, I even know that its going into the right part of the function depending on what is pressed but there are times when the interval is just not cleared and it keeps firing no matter what I do. Been working on this for hours and am totally stumped.

Edit: 
I have tried to have the var `timerGetContent` outside of the function as a global variable. This had the same behavior problems.

Edit2: 
Function that calls the `setTimers` function:

```
function slide_out(event)
{
    clicked_element = document.getElementById(event.srcElement.id);
    var re_clicked = new RegExp(clicked_element.className, "g");
    if(clicked_element.className == "options-bar slide-out")
    {
        BACKGROUND.setTimers("positive");
        clicked_element.className = clicked_element.className.replace(re_clicked, '');
        clicked_element.className += "options-bar slide-out open";
    }
    else
    {
        clicked_element.className = clicked_element.className.replace(re_clicked, '');
        clicked_element.className += "options-bar slide-out";
        BACKGROUND.setTimers("negitive");
    }
```

One other thing, the `setTimers` function is in the background file of the extension while this function is in the popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here was scoping, as Femi suggested before.  You **must** move `var timerGetContent = null;` outside the function declaration.  You also had a logic error in the first condition, `status == "login"`.  You were setting the `timerGetContent` intervalID to null without clearing it first.

So, if you called `setTimers("login");` after calling `setTimers("negitive");` without calling `setTimers("positive");` to first clear the interval, you would always have at least one interval going.

I replaced your function calls with console.log statements for testing:

```
var tray_count = 0;
var timerGetContent = null;
function setTimers(status) {
    if(status == "login") {
        tray_count = 0;
        // Setting the intervalID to null will NOT clear the interval
        // If we do not clear the interval, calling setTimers('login')
        // will create a new interval and make previous interval
        // "unclearable" every time it is called
        clearInterval(timerGetContent);
        timerGetContent = null;
        timerGetContent = setInterval(function() {
            console.log('login intervalling')
            },400);

    } else if(status == "negitive") {
        tray_count--;
        if(tray_count == 0 && timerGetContent == null) {
            timerGetContent = setInterval(function() {
                console.log('negitive intervalling')
            },400);
            alert("inside negitive");
        }
    } else if(status == "positive") {
        tray_count++;
        clearInterval(timerGetContent);
        // calling clearInterval does not actually unset the intervalID variable
        // so we need to set it to null manually
        timerGetContent = null;
        timerGetBlasts = null;
    }

}
```

Update 2014-07-14: Fixed a formatting typo --cbarrick

Comment: Thanks for the response, I moved timerGetContent outside of the function and made it global and I also cleared the interval inside of "login" and that helped with some of the erratic behavior, however I think my problem now is that javascript only runs one thread at a time and if you click on the button as it starts to execute the server call, then it finishes the server call refreshes the table and the tray goes away with out making tray_count go down.  Which then stops the auto refresh until the user clicks on something that goes into the "login" logic of setTimers.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving `var timerGetContent = null;` outside the function, so that it persists between calls to `setTimers`: right now it is local to the function.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, unfortunately I have tried that already (in fact that's how I had it set up originally). Any other suggestions?

Comment: Could you show the functions where you're calling `setTimers`? Maybe a spelling error (you use *negitive* instead of *negative*). That one is a stretch, but the only other thing I can think of is that `tray_count` isn't global and so is incorrectly being reduced to zero (and re-enabling the timer) when it shouldn't be.

Comment: tray_count is global, and thanks for pointing out the spelling error, luckily I know I am a bad speller and so copy and paste things like that just to make sure :)

Comment: Femi is absolutely correct, `var timerGetContent = null` needs to be defined outside the function, otherwise when calling `setTimers('positive');` you will always be calling `clearInterval(null)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a global array / object of timer ids such that whenever you create a new timer, you push it in and vice versa.

My take:

```
timers = {};

function slide_out(event) {
  clicked_element = document.getElementById(event.srcElement.id);

  var re_clicked = new RegExp(clicked_element.className, "g");
  if (clicked_element.className == "options-bar slide-out") {
    BACKGROUND.setTimers("positive", clicked_element.id);
    clicked_element.className = clicked_element.className.replace(re_clicked, '');
    clicked_element.className += "options-bar slide-out open";

  } else {
      clicked_element.className = clicked_element.className.replace(re_clicked, '');
      clicked_element.className += "options-bar slide-out";
      BACKGROUND.setTimers("negitive", clicked_element.id);
  }

function setTimers(status, elementId) {
  var timerGetContent = null;
  if (status == "login") {
    tray_count = 0;
    timerGetContent = null;
    timerGetContent = setInterval(getContent, 4000);
    timers[elementId] = timerGetContent;
    alert("inside login");
  } else if (status == "negitive") {
      tray_count--;
      if (tray_count == 0 && timers[elementId] == undefined) {
        timerGetContent = setInterval(getRecentContent, 4000);
        timers[elementId] = timerGetContent;
        alert("inside negitive");
      }
  } else if (status == "positive") {
      tray_count++;
      clearInterval(timers[elementId]);
      delete timers[elementId];
      timerGetContent = null;
      alert("inside positive")
  }
}
```

I am sorry if I messed up indentation

Cheers